# Using pytesseract on cropped image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am cropping an image and then using pytesseract on it to read digits from it. However, I have to first save the cropped image and then load it again for this code to work. Is there a way I can avoid doing this and improve efficiency? If I pass `cropped` directly to the `image_to_string` it crashes with:

`in image_to_string
    if len(image.split()) == 4:
    AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'split'`

```
cropped = image[1044:2000, 100:1025]
cv2.imwrite("thumbnail.png", cropped)
img = Image.open("thumbnail.png")
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config='-psm 6'))
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Image.fromarray()](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.fromarray)

`cropped = image[1044:2000, 100:1025]
img = Image.fromarray(cropped) 
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config='-psm 6'))
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))`